# Creating inequalities out of a auto-generated set of variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, constraints, minimize

in mathematica's NMinimise function I have this set up:

```
NMinimize[{1/rij, x1^2 + y1^2 <= 25, x2^2 + y2^2 <= 25, 
  x3^2 + y3^2 <= 25, x4^2 + y4^2 <= 25, x5^2 + y5^2 <= 25, 
  x6^2 + y6^2 <= 25, x7^2 + y7^2 <= 25, x8^2 + y8^2 <= 25, 
  x9^2 + y9^2 <= 25, x10^2 + y10^2 <= 25}, 
 Join[Take[xi, number], Take[yi, number]]]
```

Where xi and yi represent a list of generated variables, x1,x2,x3,x4 and so on up to x100. Rather than set lots of constraints like x1^2 + y1^2 <= 25, x2^2 + y2^2 <= 25 and so on like above id like to set one constraint to the class of variables, akin to x#^2+y#^2<=25 so the problem can be generalised up to very large n.

Ive tried inputting a list of inequalities however, mathematica does not seem to accept that as input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try working  with indexd variables as  `x[ 1],y[ 1],x[2],y[2]...x[n],y[n]`, then you can do something like ,

```
NMinimize[ Join[{1/rij},Table[x[i]^2+y[i]^2<25,{i,number}]] ,
            Flatten[Table[{x[i],y[i]]},{i,number}] ]]
```

(..untested..)

Update: now tested..

```
n = 15;
pts = Table[RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2], {n}];
s = NMinimize[ 
     Join[{Sum[Norm@({x[i], y[i]} - pts[[i]]), {i, n}]},
     Table[x[i]^2 + y[i]^2 < 1, {i, n}]], 
     Flatten[Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}]]];
```

I don't known what your rij is..

```
Graphics[ {PointSize[.05], Point /@ pts, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Red, 
          Point /@ Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}] /. Last@s}]
```

[image]